# Gradient follows mouse but doesn't catch up

Tags: javascript, jquery, gradient, mousemove

I've put together a simple jQuery script to create a radial gradient that follows the mouse with a delay, but since it's in a `mousemove` function, when the mouse stops moving the gradient doesn't catch up. Is there a simple way to make the gradient catch up with the mouse when the mouse stops without writing a function that's constantly running?

```js
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
var dX = 0;
var dY = 0;
var repeater;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  windowWidth = $(window).width();
  windowHeight = $(window).height();
  mouseXpercentage = Math.round(event.pageX / windowWidth * 100);
  mouseYpercentage = Math.round(event.pageY / windowHeight * 100);

  dX = mouseXpercentage - xPos;
  dY = mouseYpercentage - yPos;

  xPos += (dX / 50);
  yPos += (dY / 50);

  $('.rgradient').css('background', 'radial-gradient(at ' + xPos + '% ' + yPos + '%, #e6e6e6, #1e1e1e)');
});
```

```css
.rgradient {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  background: radial-gradient( at center, #e6e6e6 #1e1e1e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="rgradient"></div>
```

Comment: The gradient only moves when the mouse moves, as per how your function is setup (the mousemove listener). Instead you should separate the logic, keep variables for X,Y outside of the functions and keep the gradient moving to the mouse cursor final position even when the mouse movement stops.

Comment: To add to @MarsAndBack 's comment - you don't need a continuously running loop, you just keep looping until it catches up and no longer needs to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), as it only runs once for each frame:

```js
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
var dX = 0;
var dY = 0;
var mouseRaf = null;
var gradMoveRaf = null;

$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
  if (!mouseRaf) {
    mouseRaf = requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      windowWidth = $(window).width();
      windowHeight = $(window).height();
      
      mouseXpercentage = Math.round(event.pageX / windowWidth * 100);
      mouseYpercentage = Math.round(event.pageY / windowHeight * 100);

      dX = mouseXpercentage - xPos;
      dY = mouseYpercentage - yPos;
    
      mouseRaf = null;
    });
  }
  
  if (!gradMoveRaf) {
    gradMoveRaf = requestAnimationFrame(gradMove);
  }
});

function gradMove() {
  xPos += (dX / 50);
  yPos += (dY / 50);

  $('.rgradient').css('background', 'radial-gradient(at ' + xPos + '% ' + yPos + '%, #e6e6e6, #1e1e1e)');
  
  var absX = Math.abs(mouseXpercentage - xPos);
  var absY = Math.abs(mouseYpercentage - yPos);
  
  if (absX < 1 && absY < 1) {
    gradMoveRaf = null;
    console.log("stop");
  } else {
    gradMoveRaf = requestAnimationFrame(gradMove);
    console.log("repeat");
  }
}
```

```css
.rgradient {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1e1e1e;
  background: radial-gradient(at center, #e6e6e6 #1e1e1e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="rgradient"></div>
```